# Ingress is not working for application gateway ingress controller (AGIC) add-on of AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I enabled AGIC in the Azure portal and then created [Fanout Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout). But it's not working. I checked Rules (ingress-appgateway > Rules > Path-based routing) and paths are targeting correct backend pool.

When I am testing health probe, it's failing ("MC_..." resource group > ingress-appgateway > Health probes > Click test) - showing error :

> One or more of your backend instances are unhealthy. It is recommended
> to address this health issue first before attaching the probe

I tried:

- disabling and enabling AGIC -> **did not work**
- using `pathType: ImplementationSpecific` (instead of `pathType: Prefix`) -> **did not work**
- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` & `/foo(/|$)(.*)` -> **did not work**

At the top of the Overview page of "ingress-appgateway" (Azure portal), showing error:

> All the instances in one or more of your backend pools are unhealthy.
> This will result in a 502 error when you try to access your
> application hosted behind the Application Gateway. Please check the
> backend health and resolve the issue.

It works only If I remove paths (`/foo` & `/bar`) and target a single service.

FYI, I am using Azure CNI networking and existing VNet (dedicated subnet).

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-web-app1
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: demo-web-app1
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 4200
    targetPort: 80
    
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-web-app2
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: demo-web-app2
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-web-app1
  namespace: demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-web-app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-web-app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo-web-app1
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/myacr6472:375
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-web-app2
  namespace: demo
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-web-app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-web-app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo-web-app2
        image: myacr.azurecr.io/myacr6472:375
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-demo-web-app
  namespace: demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-web-app1
            port:
              number: 4200
      - path: /bar
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-web-app2
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: Do you check if all the pods in the running state?

Comment: Using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` doesn't make sens because you are not using nginxingress controller. You are using Application Gateway Ingress Controller so use [appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/#backend-path-prefix) annotation. Set it to `/` and let me know if it solves anything.

Comment: @Matt it's working. Should I answer using your hint ?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.  :D

Comment: @Matt now routing is not working for service exposed by `/foo`. `/foo` is working fine (hitting API service), but I need to access `/foo/abc` (`AbcController`), `/foo/xyz` (`XyzController`), which are not working. Any uri after `/foo/` is not working, any hint?

Comment: try using the echo http server image (like `mendhak/http-https-echo`) and see what paths are received by the server after the rewrite, and also if these paths exist in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Using `appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"` We will be able to specify multiple rules.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /service1/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: k8-boot-graphql-rest-aks-apm-test
            port:
              number: 8081
      - path: /service2/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: k8-sboot-restapi-test
            port:
              number: 8080

http://host/service1/actuator/health ---> Microservice 1
http://host/service2/actuator/health ---> Microservice 2
```

Sample deployment script I have used

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: k8-boot-graphql-rest-aks-apm-test
  labels:
    app: k8-boot-graphql-rest-aks-apm-test
spec:
  containers:
  - image: sreyasvpariyath/k8-boot-graphql-rest-aks-apm-test:latest #CHANGE
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: k8-boot-graphql-rest-aks-apm-test
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8-boot-graphql-rest-aks-apm-test
spec:
  selector:
    app: k8-boot-graphql-rest-aks-apm-test
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
```

Answer (score 1):

`appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: /` solved the problem as pointed out by @Matt in the comment section.

I can now target multiple backend pools using different paths i.e. `/api` for API service & `/app` for UI app.

I wrote [an article in my site about serving multiple APIs](https://hovermind.com/azure-kubernetes-service/application-gateway-ingress-controller#ingress-for-multiple-apis)